# Is there a way in mysql to convert 2 to second, 3 to third, etc. (SQL ONLY)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any formatting shorthand to do this within mysql only? In my DB, I have the number stored, but I am using a program that creates documents from templates using database queries. No stored procedures, javascript or anything fancy that you would otherwise use for this.

Before I make a switch statement, is there a better way of doing this (given the constraints) that I just don't know about. Google is failing me.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way.  I might recommend a reference table rather than a giant switch.

Comment: What is the relevant range?

Comment: @Charistine? ............

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Realistically, the range would be 1-4, but we would have outliers that could be many, many more. I was hoping there was just some sort of function I could use, but without out, the switch it is. It pulls to a document that a user has to review anyway, anything over 10 will just have to be manually edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @x=7;
select elt(@x,'first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth');
```

> seventh

Answer (score -1):

CASE is your only simple & straightforward way.
Though it depends on how far your "etc" goes, it may get really huge, obviously.

The other option could be the [User-Defined Function (UDF)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-functions.html) where you could encapsulate all the conversion logic, keeping your query simple & elegant.

Just check if your platform allows UDFs, 'cause some doesn't, like Google Cloud SQL (which is MySQL inside). And mind that it might be not that performant as you may expect from built-in functions.

Comment: No UDFs within the template queries. Switch it is. :-)